# what is an easy way to edit and manage my website that I hosted on amazon EC2

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh, webserver

Recently I hosted a website on amazon EC2.

Is there an easy way to edit my files without having to ssh and edit them on terminal?

It would be  better if I can edit them on my local computer using VScode and commit directly to the host server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VSCode  Remote SSH Extension

Follow the tutorial "[Using VSCode remotely on an EC2 instance](https://medium.com/@christyjacob4/using-vscode-remotely-on-an-ec2-instance-7822c4032cff)" from Christy Jacob

[image: remote]

You need to create an entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host aws-ec2
    HostName ec2-44-229-243-8.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/aws-key/test-key-pair.pem
```

Then you can connect to that entry from VSCode:

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/2452/1*6vmpHq9FWKfaS1dlFbblGQ.png]